# Spurious 'system\cmd.exe' in FOR /F loops

Tags: windows, for-loop, hidden, cmd

This is one of those requirements that seem to get more complicated, every time I find a Windows/cmd shell hack that need a 'work around'.  Essentially ... I need to iterate through a specific list of folders in a DOS Shell FOR loop.  Here is the loop I came up with:

```
 echo  ^ [start for test]
 for  /F "usebackq "  %%f IN (`dir /b /adh "w:\sandbox\tmp\"`)  DO (
    echo ^    do with file: %%f
    rem  <do something>
 )
echo  ^ [for test done]
```

The main need is to iterate through the hidden directories in the source folder (sandbox\tmp here).

The result is both surprising and frustrating.  This is the result from using this FOR instruction on the console command-line.

```
W:..> for  /F "usebackq "  %f 
              IN (`dir /b /adh "w:\sandbox\tmp\"`)  DO echo ^ folder = %f
File Not Found                                <1>
  folder = C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe        <2>
  folder = any                                <4>
  folder = hidden-folder-01                   <3>
  folder = hidden-folder-02                   <3>
  folder = morph                              <4>
  folder = practice-northwind                 <4>
```

Which lists five folders.  Great!  And one **cmd.exe** at label: <**2**> and a mystery at label: <**1**>. I ought to explain the **DIR** switches I think.

- /**b** ....... Bare format, just file/folder names.
- /a**dh** ..... Both hidden and directories, tried that exhaustively -- Didn't work. 
   /a**hd**
- /a**d** ...... Items with the Directory attribute (folders).
- /a**h** ...... Hidden files/folder (seemingly).

I have labelled the output and here's what I've worked out so far.

1. 'File Not Found' .. .. .. .. .. .. .. I have no idea.  I find that the "File Not Found." <**1**> is an artefact of the **/ah** switch.  When I just say: 
    IN (`dir /b /adh "w:\sandbox\tmp\"`)
2. C:\WINDOWS\system32**cmd.exe** .. .. Spurious iterator (**%%f**); this error only shows with **FOR /F** command version.   I want to find hidden directories, and the file set list doesn't return hidden files (d'oh).  So, thus far I'm stuck with the **usebackq** version of **FOR /F**.
3. Hidden Folders .. . .. .. .. .. .. .. These folders are the ***expected*****output**_.
4. Directory Folders . .. .. .. .. .. .. These files are spurious results, and not wanted.

The intended result from the CMD line version (or from the sample DOS script) is just the <**3**> items.

```
W:..> for  /F "usebackq "  %f 
              IN (`dir /b /adh "w:\sandbox\tmp\"`)  DO echo ^ folder = %f
  folder = hidden-folder-01                   <3>
  folder = hidden-folder-02                   <3>
```

Unfortunately I 'can' also get just any file in the target folder.  I think that's again to do with the HIDDEN switch (/ah).

How can I list only the hidden folders (not files) in a set directory; and iterate over the list like the FOR command?

Thanks in advance / Will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
for  /F "usebackq delims=*"  %f IN (`"dir /b /adh "%1" 2>NUL"`)  DO @echo. folder = "%f"
```

to do it.

```
2>NUL
```

will make sure the error channel (eg. file not found) is not shown and pointed to NULL (NUL)

```
delims=*
```

will make sure that the script will also work if filenames have spaces, since file names cannot have a "*" in it we will find them all!

I hope this works for you, it worked for my.

I would like to have feedback if something changes at your side, if you do not use %f but use %a, I have an idea why wou get the following line in your output

```
folder = C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe        <2>
```

Greets
PCFreak

Comment: Forgive me, but isn't that just hiding the problem?  These days I use a CALL :label  structure with loops and the like.  Saved me from a lot of headaches like this one.  Alas, I just think CMD syntax is ...

Comment: Sorry, but I think the answer is correct. You could implement things as you personally like eg. call with labels but this does not change the question!

`for  /F "usebackq delims=*"  %f IN (`"dir /s /b /a:dh "c:\" 2>NUL"`)  DO @echo. folder = "%f"` just works.

Comment: It does work by hiding whatever the real problem is about consistiency.  Two versions of the same specified/documented semantics are giving different answers.  The cure is to use bash or fish.  since I switched to Ubuntu my PC doesn't crash and simple script memes like this one work.

Answer (score 2):

In your batch file `dir /b /a dh "w:\sandbox\tmp\"` should be `dir /b /adh "w:\sandbox\tmp\"` with no space between /a and dh. With the space the dir command is interpreting dh as a directory or file paremer and is the cause of your file not found error.

When you are running from the command line you are using a different parameter to the dir command `dir /b /ah /ad "w:\sandbox\tmp\"` so you are getting different output.  With /ah and /ad as separate parameters dir seems to interpret that it should show things that are directories or hidden files while /adh will show thing that are both directories and hidden.

Also you don't need to have @ on all of your lines.  Just but @echo off at the top of the file and that will disable the command echoing for the entire batch file.

Comment: Hi shf301,

Thanks for you comments.  I found those points quite earlyon.  Unfortunately those changes don't help the problem(s).  I took the space out of the /aX command.

    dir /ah .... doesn't show hidden files or folders.
    dir /ad .... shows directories
    dir /adh and dir /ahd .... Shows absolutely NO files or directories.

In all cases in the FOR /F loop -- I get a spurious $system/cmd.exe in the list.

My leading @ is deliberate, I found it helps me when debugging script 15 years back.

/w.